# How to color an object in blender for use in Unity3d?

Tags: texturing, materials, export, unity

I have no knowledge of Modelling but I have to do this for my game. I used texture paint to color the surface. But when I import the exported fbx into unity, none of that paint is there. All I get is the raw model. How can I paint a model for use in unity?

Comment: Sounds like this might be more of a Unity question so if nobody here knows you might ask over at http://forum.unity3d.com/

Comment: As far as I know Unity can import .blend files directly, there is no need to export it to fbx.

Comment: @maddin45 yes it can. Internally .blend will be converted to fbx. But that is not the point. Even if it is imported as .blend, the colors don't show.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply your texture image in Unity. Put the image in your Unity assets folder, then you can drag and drop the texture straight onto your model, that's how I've always done it anyway

Also, I think you can export the texture with the model if you load the texture onto your material slot in blender, but I always find the first way simpler

Comment: What about UV mapping?

Comment: Don't know exactly how it works but I think the UV's just get transferred with the model. When you apply the texture in Unity it is always correctly mapped (When I've done it anyway)

Comment: Most probably you were supplied a model with UV mapped texture :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean? If you've made a model and textured it in Blender, you had to do the UV mapping before texturing?

Comment: Yes. As far as i know, applying texture requires unwrapping the model and UV mapping the texture to fit the model.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion yet?

Comment: Not yet. But i'm sure unity needs that meta data. It can't apply image as texture automatically.